# NullReferenceException returned by Messenger.Default.Send("any string");

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

In my app:

```
Messenger.Default.Send("Search Returned");
```

message is 'NullReferenceException', no inner exception.

???

Comment: Please show the full stack trace

Comment: Need more information, the line above works - even if no recipient is defined. Need more code to advise.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are registering for the message in your initialization path.

```
Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, YourHandlerMethod)
```

Comment: The Messenger does not require a recipient. The code in the OP should work even if no recipient is registered - just tested it and it worked.